# more functional programing way to handle data - javascript es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, functional-programming

I want to handle the rows data if it's length more than 4 result, merge it's value together, how to deal with it more functional programming way?

origin:

```
rows: [{
  id: '1',
  value: 10
}, {
  id: '2',
  value: 13
}, {
  id: '3',
  value: 21
}, {
  id: '4',
  value: 22
}, {
  id: '5',
  value: 23
}]
```

I want to use map, reduce, format the data to following:

```
// mrege the more result's value together into the "4"
rows: [{
  id: '1',
  value: 10
}, {
  id: '2',
  value: 13
}, {
  id: '3',
  value: 21
}, {
  id: '4',
  value: 45
}]
```

Comment: More functionnal as opposed to what? You haven't shown any code.

Comment: Please show the code what you tried. Also, merge with what? always with 4th id?

Comment: sorry, I have update my question

Comment: sorry about this bad post, I don't clarify my question, sorry :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some *ES6 features* and *array.prototype.reduce*:

```js
var rows = [{ id: '1', value: 10 }, { id: '2', value: 13 }, { id: '3',  value: 21 }, { id: '4', value: 22 }, { id: '5', value: 23 }];

var [a, b, c, ...rest] = rows;
var res = [a, b, c, rest.reduce((m, o) => (m.value += o.value, m), { id: rest[0].id, value: 0 })];

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Though I disagree answering such post, this is a good answer. +1

Comment: I face the coding style error with "rest.reduce((m, o) => (m.value += o.value, m), { id: rest[0].id, value: 0 })" here, is there any idea to fixed? :(

Comment: @KevinHu What is the coding style error ?

Comment: Arrow function should not return assignment. (no-return-assign)

Comment: You can avoid this error by doing: rest.reduce((m, o) => { m.value += o.value; return m; }, { id: rest[0].id, value: 0 })

Comment: fyi: this program generates in error in the scenario where less than 4 rows of data are given – *"cannot read property `id` of undefined"*

Comment: @KevinHu, `(o, m) => Object.assign(m, { value: m.value + o.value })` would do the same but uses an expression instead of a statement – or using destructuring `({id, value:x}, {value:y}) => ({ id, value: x + y })`

Comment: I think I will use callback function inside reduce, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `reduce` to iterate through your array. If index is less than 4, just push to the array, if more than 4 add the value to the last element:

```js
const rows = [{
  id: '1',
  value: 10
}, {
  id: '2',
  value: 13
}, {
  id: '3',
  value: 21
}, {
  id: '4',
  value: 22
}, {
  id: '5',
  value: 23
}];

const result = rows.reduce((acc, elt, index) => {
  if (index < 4) {
    acc.push(elt);
  } else {
    acc[3].value += elt.value;
  }
  
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Please do not answer post that do not show any sign of effort. It just promotes spoon feeding.

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching a way to handle array according to your want, consider using prototypes as shown below.

```js
//Assuming that the array elements are added using rows.add()
rows =  [];
/*A Prototype that checks the length of array and pushes 
item if less that 4 else merges the value of the new data 
with the last one*/
rows.add = function(val) {
  if(this.length == 4)  {
   this[this.length-1].value += val.value;
  } else {
    this.push(val);
  }
}
//Adding the elements using add
rows.add( { id : '1', value : 24});
rows.add( { id : '2', value : 21});
rows.add( { id : '3', value : 23});
rows.add( { id : '4', value : 2});
console.log(rows);
rows.add( { id : '5', value : 22});
console.log(rows);
rows.add( { id : '6', value : 22});
console.log(rows);
rows.add( { id : '7', value : 22});
console.log(rows);
```